# How would I pass additional parameters to MatchEvaluator

Tags: c#, matchevaluator

I have a bit of code that looks like this:

```
text = reg.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(MatchEvalStuff));
```

I need to pass in a 2nd parameter like this:

```
text = reg.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(MatchEvalStuff, otherData));
```

Is this possible, and what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm using 2.0, so I don't have access to lambdas. Here is what I ended up doing:

```
private string MyMethod(Match match, bool param1, int param2)
{
    //Do stuff here
}

Regex reg = new Regex(@"{regex goes here}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Content = reg.Replace(Content, new MatchEvaluator(delegate(Match match) { return MyMethod(match, false, 0); }));
```

This way I can create a "MyMethod" method and pass it whatever parameters I need to (param1 and param2 are just for this example, not the code I actually used).

Answer (score 31):

MatchEvaluator is a delegate so you can't change its signature.  You can create a delegate that calls a method with an additional parameter.  This is pretty easy to do with lambda expressions:

```
text = reg.Replace(text, match => MatchEvalStuff(match, otherData));
```

Comment: An alternative way to do it based on this solution `text = Regex.Replace(text, @"some_pattern", new MatchEvaluator(match => MatchEvalStuff(match, otherData)));`

Comment: Sorry, I know this is old, but any chance someone could extend this answer with the delegate declaration please, I can't wrap my head around it?